# How do I find the second lowest value of inputs using while loops in python?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

students = int(input('Enter number of students: '))
counter = 1

while (counter <= students):

```
name = input('Please enter student ' + str(counter) + ' name:')
score = int(input('Please enter student ' + str(counter) + ' score:'))

lowest = 100
secondlowest = 100

if (score < lowest):
    secondlowest = lowest
    lowest = score

elif score > lowest and score < secondlowest:
    secondlowest = score

counter = counter + 1

print("2nd lowest student is " + name + " with score " + str(secondlowest))
```

Comment: You can simply use an extra variable. When you find a smallest number, the oldest is the second, if you find another one, the first goes to second and this replaces first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need two variables to keep track of the two lowest scores

- If the newest score is lower than the lowest score, update that and set the second lowest to the first
- Otherwise, if the newest score is lower than the current second lowest, just update that with the new value.

Comment: how do i do that?

Comment: can u please put it in code i don't understand thank you tho

Comment: @Iambadatpython - My answer is pseudo-code to help with your learning, the two bullet points are an if statement and and elif statement that you'll need, "newest score" would be your current `score` variable, you just need to add in a `lowest_score` and `second_lowest_score` variable

Comment: yea but like what do the if statements look like I don't know how to do that

Comment: sorry i am super dumb

Comment: @Iambadatpython - Its fine but you should have a go yourself, what part exactly with the statement are you unsure of?

Comment: i don't understand anything to be honest

Comment: i get what you're saying but i don't know how to do it

Comment: You need to do some research, searching on google for "python if statement" or "python elif" statement should be enough to get started

Comment: @Iambadatpython - Good luck! when you're ready, in each bullet point of my answer, the bit before the comma is what goes in the if/elif statement, and the bit after the comma goes under it

Comment: lowest = 100
        secondlowest = 100
    
        if (score < lowest):
            secondlowest = lowest
            lowest = score
        
        elif score > lowest and score < secondlowest:
            secondlowest = score

Comment: look at edited question above those are my if statements but it's not working

Comment: please look above im so sorry i need u bro

Comment: That looks about correct except the elif doesn't need to check `score > lowest`... what does not working mean?

Comment: I'm on my phone atm but your issue was you reset the lowest and second lowest within your while loop. https://ideone.com/1YV7Ou.   Now you just need to use another variable to keep track of the name of the second lowest ..